# Can the light horse from Mount spell be used by allies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Referring to the spell [Mount](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mount):

> You summon a light horse or a pony (your choice) **to serve *you*** as a
>   mount. The steed serves willingly and well. The mount comes with a bit
>   and bridle and a riding saddle.

Emphasis mine.

Is there any way to positively determine if this is inclusive or exclusive, otherwise a wizard with a plan for the party to escape quickly is going to quickly be left in the lurch.

To the extent of this question of control, does this mean a hostile enemy may be able to jump onto the summoned horse before you, and then be able to control it as the Ride skill allows? Would you then only be able to dismiss the spell if you wanted to end this Grand Theft Equine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

Of course, the mount serves *you*, so it will do whatever you tell it to do; this includes being a mount to designated creatures. As soon as you say *"dismount that guy"*, however, they should fall off the mount.

> You summon a light horse or a pony (your choice) to serve you as a mount. The steed serves willingly and well. The mount comes with a bit and bridle and a riding saddle.

Otherwise, the *Communal* version would be unusable, as it states that you summon multiple mounts, but who would mount them unless you could multiply yourself?

> This spell functions like mount, except you can summon up to six light horses or ponies, and you divide the duration in 2-hour increments among the steeds summoned.